# How to use Global.asa with API

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am attempting to use an API to return a website visitor's latitude, longitude, city, state, and zip code. I found one I like - [GEO IPIFY](https://geo.ipify.org/)

Challenge I have is my website(s) is done in classic ASP and the examples for the API are in C#, JAVA, Python, etc.

What I am trying to achieve is getting the needed values, lat, lng, zip, etc, in my global.asa and setting them as session variables. The example below is for VB.net.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Class Program
    Public Const IP As String = "63.148.239.195"
    Public Const API_KEY As String = "at_6ZsRWjq..."
    Public Const API_URL As String = "https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?"

    Private Shared Sub Main()
        Dim url As String = API_URL & $"apiKey={API_KEY}&ipAddress={IP}"
        Dim resultData As String = String.Empty
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        Using response As HttpWebResponse = CType(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Using stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
                    resultData = reader.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Console.WriteLine(resultData)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The `global.asa` file in Classic ASP uses VBScript not VB.Net so not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global.asa has a `Session_OnStart` sub, but you're quite limited in what you can do within the Global.asa file, so trying to call the API from `Session_OnStart` is going to lead to issues. You also can't use `Session_OnStart` outside of Global.asa or call any functions or sub routines from within Global.asa unless the functions/subs are also coded into Global.asa.

What I like to do is create a `global.asp` file, which I use to set various application settings, include site-wide classes and store important functions and sub routines that are needed throughout my site. I then include `global.asp` on all pages of my asp site. Within `global.asp` you could set a sub that calls the ipify.org api and stores the results as session variables with the help of a [JSON class](https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON). You could then call the sub on each page load and exit the sub if the api has already been called during the users session, or make a new call if it's a new session.

global.asp

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%

    ' Set some useful application settings, constants, other site-wide classes etc...

    Server.ScriptTimeout = 20
    Session.Timeout = 720
    Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
    Response.LCID = 1033

%>
<!--#include virtual = "/classes/jsonObject.class.asp" -->
<%

    Sub ipify()

        ' Only call the ipify API once per session (but try 3 times)
        ' If session("ipify_called") is true or 3+ attempts have been  
        ' made to call the API then exit the sub

        if session("ipify_called") OR session("ipify_attempts") >= 3 then exit sub

        ' Assign a value of 0 to ipify_attempts if this is a new session

        if isEmpty(session("ipify_attempts")) then session("ipify_attempts") = 0

        Const api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"
        Const api_url = "https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1"

        Dim rest : Set rest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        rest.open "GET", api_url, False
        rest.send "apiKey=" & api_key & "&ipAddress=" & Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")

        if rest.status = 200 then

            Dim JSON : Set JSON = New JSONobject
            Dim oJSONoutput : Set oJSONoutput = JSON.Parse(rest.responseText)

                if isObject(oJSONoutput("location")) then

                    session("ipify_country") = oJSONoutput("location")("country")
                    session("ipify_region") = oJSONoutput("location")("region")
                    session("ipify_city") = oJSONoutput("location")("city")
                    session("ipify_lat") = oJSONoutput("location")("lat")
                    session("ipify_lng") = oJSONoutput("location")("lng")
                    session("ipify_postalCode") = oJSONoutput("location")("postalCode")
                    session("ipify_timezone") = oJSONoutput("location")("timezone")

                    ' To prevent the api from being called again during this session

                    session("ipify_called") = true

                else

                    ' oJSONoutput("location") should be an object, but it isn't.
                    ' The rest.responseText is probably invalid

                    session("ipify_attempts") = session("ipify_attempts") + 1

                end if

            Set oJSONoutput = nothing
            Set JSON = nothing

        else

            ' Unexpected status code, probably a good idea to log the rest.responseText

            session("ipify_attempts") = session("ipify_attempts") + 1

        end if

        set rest = nothing

    End Sub


    ' Call the ipify sub on each page load.

    Call ipify()

%>
```

JSON Class used:
https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON

Be sure to include global.asp on other pages of your asp site:

`<!--#include virtual = "/global.asp" -->`

Comment: Great answer but feel you're wasting your time as the question just doesn't deserve it. That code they posted is directly from the https://geo.ipify.org/ they haven't even attempted to try something themselves and now you just validated their decision not to.

Comment: Thank you Adam. I created a directory, and a file therein called default.asp  In that file I copied your code exactly, and put in my key. Then I uploaded the file jsonObject.class.asp in the same directory. When I open the default.asp page I see a bunch of content that looks like the website GIT, and at the bottom I see this -  

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01fa'

Class not defined: 'JSONobject'

/stackOverFlow/Default.asp, line 36

Comment: In my example code 'jsonObject.class.asp' is in a sub directory called 'classes'. You're also kinda missing the point if you're trying to run the code in a standalone page. As I explained it would make more sense to create a global include file. And I don't know what you mean by "a bunch of content that looks like the website GIT".

Comment: @Adam like I said, you're wasting your time.

Comment: @Lankymart It's looking that way :(

Comment: @TMHDesign That may be true (sorry Lankymart), but he's also helped a lot of people on here. When posting a question it's common courtesy to outline the steps you've already taken trying to get your code to work and provide examples for other developers to look at and try and figure out where you're going wrong. It's not really intended as a "how do I do this?" type forum, there are plenty of online tutorials for that sort of thing if you take the time to research. Although having said all that, your question posed an interesting challenge and I enjoyed answering it. I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: @Adam water off a ducks back. If someone is willing to help themselves by having the common courtesy to put together a conherent question with examples of what they have tried, then I’m willing to help them.

Comment: @Adam while you feel questions are challenging you continue to jump on every question going regardless of effort / quality by an OP. Once it’s no longer a challenge you'll lose interest and realise it’s pointless answering the same questions over and over again.

Comment: Fair enough, but often times comments such as his are not productive and deter newbies from using this valuable online resource. Of course there will be those who will abuse it, but they are often weeded out rather quickly. In the question I asked, the examples provided were all in languages I did not know. What I was after was a vbscript example and I could not find one. That is why I did not have an attempt posted. I just wanted to know how to do the equivalent with a global.asa file, or something along that lines. Your example was stellar. Let's hope Lankymart find happiness one day...

Comment: @Lankymart you're probably right. TBH I have a bit of downtime ATM and am just trying to up my reputation, I'm sure my desire to help will fade over time, as it usually does. But hopefully someone else with this same question will find my answer helpful in the future. I know I've found a lot of answers on StackOverflow in the past, and I enjoy feeling like I'm giving a bit back, never mind how small

Comment: @TMHDesign maybe that is where the confusion / misunderstanding is, [so] isn’t a site for *”newbies”*. It is designed as a canonical resource for programmers by programmers and is no substitute for a good tutorial or book if you’re just starting out with a specific programming / scripting language.